# How to SELECT based on value of another SELECT for the same month value

Tags: mysql

So, I have two data and they did't have any relationship

first Table

```
tglAmbil    Satuan  Harga
11-08-2017  1       10000
11-08-2017  2       10000
15-08-2017  2       10000
01-09-2017  2       10000
```

Second Table

```
tglAmbil    Satuan  Harga
21-08-2017  1       10000
```

And I try to make my SELECT result look like this:

```
Month(tglAmbil)    date_format(tglAmbil,"$m")  Harga
8                  Agustus                     60000
9                  September                   20000
```

using this query:

```
SELECT 

MONTH(`tglAmbil`),

DATE_FORMAT(tglAmbil,"%M"),

SUM(detaillpjunbudged.satuan * detaillpjunbudged.harga) + 
IFNULL(prokers.total,0) 

FROM `unbudged` LEFT JOIN lpjunbudged ON unbudged.kdUnbudgeding = 
lpjunbudged.kdUnbudgeding 

LEFT JOIN detaillpjunbudged ON lpjunbudged.kdLpjUnbudged = 
detaillpjunbudged.kdLpjUnbudged,

(SELECT MONTH(`tglAmbil`) AS 
tgl,DATE_FORMAT(tglAmbil,"%M"),SUM(detaillpjproker.satuan * 
detaillpjproker.harga) AS total,`kdDetailProker` FROM `realisasiproker` LEFT 
JOIN lpjproker ON realisasiproker.kdRealisasiProker = 
lpjproker.kdRealisasiProker LEFT JOIN detaillpjproker ON lpjproker.kdLPJ = 
detaillpjproker.kdLPJ GROUP BY MONTH(tglAmbil)) AS prokers 

WHERE MONTH(`tglAmbil`) = prokers.tgl GROUP BY MONTH(`tglAmbil`)
```

but the result that I got is:

```
Month(tglAmbil)    date_format(tglAmbil,"$m")  Harga
8                  Agustus                     60000
```

so, what the real cause? I confused with this sytax problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;

CREATE TABLE table1
(purchase_date DATE NOT NULL
,quantity INT NOT NULL
,price INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
('2017-08-11',1,10000),
('2017-08-11',2,10000),
('2017-08-15',2,10000),
('2017-09-01',2,10000);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table2;

CREATE TABLE table2
(purchase_date DATE NOT NULL
,quantity INT NOT NULL
,price INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES
('2017-08-21',1,10000);


SELECT DATE_FORMAT(purchase_date,'%Y-%m') yearmonth
     , SUM(quantity*price) total 
  FROM
     (
     SELECT * FROM table1
      UNION
     SELECT * FROM table2
     ) x
 GROUP 
    BY yearmonth;
+-----------+-------+
| yearmonth | total |
+-----------+-------+
| 2017-08   | 60000 |
| 2017-09   | 20000 |
+-----------+-------+
```

Comment: thank you, It's work when I try it on my own table. but when I check the value why the SUM value did't same with the actual value (exaple: the real value is 23305000 but it only show the value 23255000).

Comment: ah, sorry. Nevermind about my last comment question. I already figure out the problems.